# FFMPEG command issue

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am running an [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) command to build a video: first 5 seconds are intro, middle has slideshow of images with overlaying watermark image, and 5 second exit scene with audio over the top of the entire video. This process has been working. But, one time I tried running it, it through the error:

```
Input link in2:v0 parameters (size 1282x720, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1280x720, SAR 1:1)
```

Here is the command:

```
ffmpeg -y -t 5.000000 \
-loop 1 -i splash.png \
-i img-1.jpg \
-i img-2.jpg \
-i img-3.jpg \
-f lavfi -i color=black:r=25:s=1280x720:d=15.000000  \
-loop 1 -i watermark.png -t 5.000000 \
-loop 1 \
-i exit.png \
-i final.mp3 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.500000,fade=t=out:st=4.500000:d=0.500000[splash]; \
[6:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.500000,fade=t=out:st=4.500000:d=0.500000[end]; \
[1:v]scale=iw*max(1280*5/iw\,720*5/ih):ih*max(1280*5/iw\,720*5/ih):flags=lanczos,crop=1280*5:720*5,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0005,1.1)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=125,setsar=1,setdar=16/9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
[2:v]scale=iw*max(1280*5/iw\,720*5/ih):ih*max(1280*5/iw\,720*5/ih):flags=lanczos,crop=1280*5:720*5,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0005,1.1)':x=0:y=2880:d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.500000:alpha=1,setsar=1,setdar=16/9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+5.000000/TB[v2]; \
[3:v]scale=iw*max(1280*5/iw\,720*5/ih):ih*max(1280*5/iw\,720*5/ih):flags=lanczos,crop=1280*5:720*5,zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.1,max(1.001,zoom-0.0005))':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y=0:d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.500000:alpha=1,setsar=1,setdar=16/9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10.000000/TB[v3]; \
[4:v][v1]overlay[over1]; \
[over1][v2]overlay[over2]; \
[over2][v3]overlay[over3]; \
[over3][5:v]overlay=shortest=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.500000,fade=t=out:st=14.500000:d=0.500000[main];\
[splash][main][end]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[v]" \
-c:v libx264 -map [v] -crf 18 -map 7:a -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

And the output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.1.4-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.1 (Debian 5.4.1-2) 20160904
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libwebp --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libfreetype --enable-fontconfig --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-gray --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libass --enable-gnutls --enable-libvidstab --enable-libsoxr --enable-frei0r --enable-libfribidi --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --enable-librtmp --enable-libzimg --cc=gcc-5 --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'splash.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1280x720 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, image2, from 'img-1.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 85822 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 2560x1704 [SAR 1:1 DAR 320:213], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #2, image2, from 'img-2.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 40378 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 2560x1704 [SAR 1:1 DAR 320:213], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #3, image2, from 'img-3.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 43527 kb/s
    Stream #3:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 2560x1708 [SAR 1:1 DAR 640:427], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #4, lavfi, from 'color=black:r=25:s=1280x720:d=15.000000':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #4:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #5, png_pipe, from 'watermark.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #5:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1280x720 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #6, png_pipe, from 'exit.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #6:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1282x720 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 641:360], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #7, mp3, from 'final.mp3':
  Metadata:
    artist          : Music 2 Hues
    album           : Vol. 23 Light Jazz
    album_artist    : Music 2 Hues
    title           : Dream River 60 Sec
    encoded_by      : iTunes v7.0.2.16
    track           : 26
    genre           : Jazz
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
  Duration: 00:00:25.05, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #7:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 64 kb/s
[swscaler @ 0x58a4280] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x59b9720] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5aca920] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[Parsed_concat_30 @ 0x51d9b20] Input link in2:v0 parameters (size 1282x720, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1280x720, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_concat_30 @ 0x51d9b20] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_30
Error configuring complex filters.
Invalid argument
2016/10/17 09:29:27 exit status 1
exit status 1
```

There are different images that are processed using this command every time which is why the sar/dar is specified in the command. And it has worked for all images I have provided it so far. Why would these images all of the sudden throw this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `exit.png` has different resolution (1282x720) in compared with other streams (1280x720) and `concat` filter can't do its job.
you can scale it to be same as others. to do that, edit second line of `filter_complex` in this way:
`...[6:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.500000,fade=t=out:st=4.500000:d=0.500000,scale=1280:720,setsar=1[end]; \
...`

Comment: Awesome. That was it. Thank you! Can't believe I didn't see that.